# Почему импортированные шрифты от гугла неверно отображаются на сайте?

Tags: шрифты

Импортировал шрифты от гугла

> @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cuprum:400,700&subset=latin,cyrillic);
> @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:700,400&subset=cyrillic,latin);

Шрифты отображение вообще непонятно какое... помогите. что можно сделать?
сайт http://stanok74.ru

спасибо!

Comment: Вроде нормально отображаются

Comment: а в import текст в кавычки брать не нужно?

@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cuprum:400,700&subset=latin,cyrillic'); @import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:700,400&subset=cyrillic,latin');